# how to display multiple fields of data in a row as column in a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to display rows of data in a as columns in a Crystal report....so that I get data from row one in column 1, data from row 2 in Column 2, etc....? 
so to display vertically in one column. So as you look across columns you could see how things changed over time. 
New to crystal need to know if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Right Click on a Section then go to Section expert and then check Format with Multiple columns
and then set your printing directions

[image]

[image]